# Django admin page redirects to default home page

Tags: django, django-admin, django-views

Please note that I am a newbie at django and a semi-newbie at python.

My admin page (`localhost:8000/admin`) seems to have gone missing - it reverts back to the *welcome - it works* page and not the admin page.

This is the main `urls.py` page:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', '{{ project_name }}.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^{{ project_name }}/', include('{{ project_name }}.foo.urls')),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    # url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
 )
```

Here is the app settings

```
    INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'urm',
    'south',

)
```

this is admin (urm)

```
from django.contrib import admin
from urm.models import *

class urm(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields =['blogger']

admin.site.register(urm)
```

The database is synced and urm is properly migrated.

It is preventing me from understanding how to build my own views - do you all know what the issue is that i'm totally blind to? I'm using south and postgres - but I'm basically following the tutorial and migrating where I am suppose to sync (unless I figured out otherwise)

Thank you!

Comment: in your `class urm` what is the model? `model=BlahBlah` ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need the sites framework, so the easiest fix would be to remove the following item from your INSTALLED_APPS and i think the error should go away:

```
'django.contrib.sites'
```